# Confusion Regarding Files, Attachment, Document,chatter and Content Distribution

Tags: attachment, contentdocument, chatter-file

I was fiddling with various ways to store files in salesforce.
Files, Attachment, Document,chatter and Content Distribution and many more. 
I believe all of these consume the FileStorage of salesforce. Am confused about when to use what. I googled through salesforce docs and coudnt't find specific use cases when to use which mechanism. Can someone throw some light about these File Storage options

Comment: refer this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&language=en_US&type=0, is that not good enough?

Comment: I already went through that. Was thinking from Programmer point of  view, which one should be preferred over other when one has a choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Good Question, I'll share my umderstanding
->**Files**: Upload a file and store it privately until you're ready to share it. Share the file with coworkers and groups **to collaborate and get feedback**. **Attach files to posts in a Chatter feed on the Home tab, Chatter tab, a profile, a record, or a group**. Users with access to Salesforce Files Sync can access, sync, and share files in their Salesforce Files Sync folder.

->**Content:** Create, clone, or modify a sales presentation and save it so only you can see it and work on it. When you're ready, **publish it so other users in your company** have access to it. **Create a content pack and send it to customers**.

->**Documents:** Add a custom logo to meeting requests by uploading your logo to the Documents tab. When you are using just about any 3rd party app in SalesForce, **their logos and other graphics have to be in a Documents** folder for SF to recoginize them.  **Documents** folders **are just URLs** whereas to display **Content SF delivers it differently**.

->**Attachment:** Add a file to a **specific record**, like an event, marketing campaign, contact, or case by attaching it on the Attachments related list.

Reference: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&language=en_US&type=0